# sql - check to see if an entry exists, if so update,is if not insert

Tags: sql

I was wondering if there was a way that I can do the folloing in one sql statement.

I am parsing an csv file for product insertion into the database. is there a way that I can check to see if an entry in a table with *X* equaling to *N*, if so update the rest f the columns else insert it?

regards

Phil

Answer (score 3):

This type of operation is sometimes called an "UPSERT". The SQL standard way to do it is to use the [`MERGE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29) statement, but unfortunately it is not widely implemented yet.

Some databases have added their own ways to do it, such as the non-standard MySQL extensions [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) and [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 1):

The [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement will get you there, but it's only available on SQL Server 2008 R2.  You would otherwise need to treat this as a Slowly Changing Dimension and either bring the data into a temp table and compare or use an integration services package to do the work.

Comment: It's not only SQL Server. Oracle and DB2 also support the MERGE statement

Comment: Actually, it is in SQL Server **2008** (non-R2) also.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
if(update myTable where x='n')
else{
 insert into myTable(x,y,z) values(1,2,3)
}
```

The update query will run regardless, and will return false if it couldn't update that record, causing it to do the insert.